# Prove or disprove the following: {$q \in \Bbb Q : 2 \leq q^2 \leq 4$} is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $\Bbb Q$ be the set of rational number. Let d be a metric defined by $d(p,q) = |p-q|,  \forall p,q \in \Bbb Q$
Then prove or disprove the following:

{$q \in \Bbb Q : 2 \leq q^2 \leq 4$} is compact.

My Attempt:

{$q \in \Bbb Q : 2 \leq q^2 \leq 4$} = $[\sqrt2,2] \cap \Bbb Q$ which is closed as it is finite intersection of closed sets. Also {$q \in \Bbb Q : 2 \leq q^2 \leq 4$} = $[\sqrt2,2] \cap \Bbb Q$ is bounded because $[\sqrt2,2]$ is bounded.
Hence
{$q \in \Bbb Q : 2 \leq q^2 \leq 4$} is compact. But given answer is "not compact". I think that I made a silly mistake. Please point out my mistake or provide a solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

$\mathbb{Q}$ is not closed, we can construct a sequence of rational number that converges to $\sqrt2$, which is not a rational number.

Comment: Please provide me a sequence of rational numbers that converges to $\sqrt2$

Comment: $x_1=2, x_{n+1} =\frac12 x_n + \frac1{x_n}$.

Comment: Yes, $\Bbb Q$ is not closed. But given that $\{q \in \Bbb Q : 2 \leq q^2 \leq4\}$ is closed and bounded.